# Catching variables in simple defer vs deferred anonymous function

Tags: go

Let's look at following code:

```
func main() {
  x := "hello"
  defer fmt.Println(x)

  x = "world"
  defer func() {
     fmt.Println(x)
  }()

  defer fmt.Println(x)

  x = "qwerty"
```

}

I know that defers are executed in LIFO order. I think they are pushed to the stack and variables values will be equal to the value when they are pushed. So the output will be:

world

qwerty

hello

The thing I don't understand is difference between simple defer and anonymous defer. We can notice that when deferred anonymous function is executed, it somehow knows the last value of `x`. How does it know it? If, in the place of anonymous function would be simple defer, the output would be different.

Comment: Each time a "defer" statement executes, the **function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved** anew but the **actual function is not invoked**. `x` is evaluated and saved in `defer fmt.Println(x)`, not so in `defer func() {<body of func is NOT evaluated>} ()`. https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements

Comment: A defer that uses an anonymous function, as far as your question is concerned, isn't any different from any other use of anonymous functions, or [function literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Function_literals): *"Function literals are closures: they may refer to variables defined in a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as long as they are accessible."*